# OSX capture window CONTENTS w/o title bar OSX cruft

Tags: screenshot

Ideally there's something easy to install that allows one to easily capture a window's contents (without the OSX frame) without having to cut/paste/edit/crop/rubberband nonsense.

There's a bunch of screen capture tools, but none that seem to advertise this as a feature anyway. Does this exist?